# Get first and last record for each group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables like

[image]

[image]

My output should look like this. Basically, latest and the first status for each user_unique_access_id along with the timestamp

[image]

I tried the below query but my output has duplicated records.

```
select
    distinct u.user_unique_access_id,
    first_value(ul.status) over (partition by u.user_unique_access_id
order by
    ul.created_timestamp asc) as first_status,
    min(ul.created_timestamp) as first_created_at,
    first_value(ul.status) over (partition by u.user_unique_access_id
order by
    ul.created_timestamp desc) as current_status,
    max(ul.created_timestamp) as last_created_at
from
    public.users u
join public.user_location ul on
    u.user_key = ul.user_key
group by
    u.user_unique_access_id,
    u.user_name,
    ul.status,
    ul.created_timestamp ;
```

[image]

DDL and DML statement

```
create table public.users ( user_key serial primary key, user_name varchar(20), user_unique_access_id varchar(20) );

create table public.user_location( user_key bigint not null, STATUS VARCHAR (512) not null, CREATED_TIMESTAMP timestamp not null, foreign key (user_key) references public.users (user_key) );

insert
    into
    public.users ( user_unique_access_id, user_name)
values('ABC_1', 'ABC');

insert
    into
    public.users ( user_unique_access_id, user_name)
values('ABC_2', 'ABC');

insert
    into
    public.user_location (user_key, status, created_timestamp)
values(1, 'Entrance', current_timestamp);

insert
    into
    public.user_location (user_key, status, created_timestamp)
values(1, 'Building A', current_timestamp);

insert
    into
    public.user_location (user_key, status, created_timestamp)
values(1, 'Building B', current_timestamp);

insert
    into
    public.user_location (user_key, status, created_timestamp)
values(1, 'Exit', current_timestamp);

insert
    into
    public.user_location (user_key, status, created_timestamp)
values(2, 'Entrance', current_timestamp);

insert
    into
    public.user_location (user_key, status, created_timestamp)
values(2, 'Building A', current_timestamp);
```

Comment: You group by fields that you do not include in the select clause (like `ul.created_timestamp`), and so any variation in those "hidden" fields will go unnoticed, and you'll get "duplicates"...

Comment: @trincot I have provided it in the select clause min(ul.created_timestamp) as first_created_at,

Comment: It makes no sense to apply aggregation to a field you group by. Either select it without aggregation, or remove it from the group-by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the "first" and the "last" record using `DISTINCT ON`. Use that in two derived tables (one for the "first", one for the "last" record) and left join these to `users`.

```
SELECT u.user_unique_access_id,
       f.status,
       f.created_timestamp,
       l.status,
       l.created_timestamp
       FROM users u
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (ul.user_key)
                              ul.user_key,
                              ul.status,
                              ul.created_timestamp
                              FROM user_location ul
                              ORDER BY ul.user_key ASC,
                                       ul.created_timestamp DESC) f
                      ON f.user_key = u.user_key
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (ul.user_key)
                              ul.user_key,
                              ul.status,
                              ul.created_timestamp
                              FROM user_location ul
                              ORDER BY ul.user_key ASC,
                                       ul.created_timestamp ASC) l
                      ON l.user_key = u.user_key;
```

(I would have linked a db<>fiddle but your DML is pretty useless as the timestamps are all the same.)